# ActiveX events not work in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I have next code in my website. This code is an c# activex, the function alert(MyCC.GetID().Fullname) works but events not work. What i doing wrong?

```
<object id="MyCC" codebase="http://localhost:3239/WebDAVCab.CAB" 
  classid="clsid:5F9A5DDB-0D35-4893-A9ED-1FAFFE94373A" width="80" height="120" VIEWASTEXT>
</object>

<script type="text/javascript">
        MyCC = document.getElementById("MyCC");
        alert(MyCC.GetID().Fullname);

        MyCC.CardInserted = OnCardInserted;
        MyCC.CardRemoved = OnCardRemoved;

        function OnCardInserted()
        {
            alert("raised");
        }
        function OnCardRemoved()
        {
            alert("raised2");
        } 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for sinking these events in Javascript is as follows:

```
function MyCC::CardInserted () { }
```

or

```
MyCC::CardInserted = function () { }
```

Naturally, you don't have to specify an anonymous function:

```
MyCC::CardInserted = OnCardInserted;
```

Comment: I tested but return a error in MyCC:: i get a ie error Expected ;

Answer (score 1):

In order to attach the event to the ActiveX you can use the Andy E solution, but with eval:

```
<object name="MyCC" id="MyCC" codebase="http://localhost:3239/WebDAVCab.CAB" 
  classid="clsid:5F9A5DDB-0D35-4893-A9ED-1FAFFE94373A" width="80" height="120" VIEWASTEXT>
</object>

<script type="text/javascript">

    eval("function MyCC::CardInserted () {return OnCardInserted();}");
    eval("function MyCC::CardRemoved () {return OnCardRemoved();}");

    function OnCardInserted()
    {
        alert("raised");
    }
    function OnCardRemoved()
    {
        alert("raised2");
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. try using `MyCC.attachEvent('CardInserted', OnCardInserted);` instead
2. You also need to implement [IObjectSafety](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/NETFrameworkinterop/Jan2006/post24884633.asp)

Comment: I tried but not fire. Introduced this control in windows forms and work very well, all events is fired in windows forms but no in html/javascript.